# Unable to run the method fit for svm (by scikit-learn)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to generate an svm predictor using the sklearn library.
But, every time I try to run `fit(X,Y)` I get the following error:

> The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1

I am pretty sure the problem is with the `y_learn` var because if I change `y_learn` to a list where the first element is `1` and the others are `0`, it works.

My code is:

```
clf = svm.SVC()

clf.fit(x_learn,y_learn)
```

where

```
y_learn = [ 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
```

and `type(y_learn) = type 'numpy.ndarray'`

```
x_learn = [array([  9.40768535e-01,   8.41994398e-01,   9.32081721e-01,
         5.66162508e-02,   7.98723422e-03,   1.43783134e-02,
        -7.09941391e-03,  -3.47126563e-03,   7.56540837e+01]), array([  9.51510849e-01,   8.45112974e-01,   9.38219301e-01,
         5.82776713e-02,   8.91018076e-03,   1.14186585e-02,
         1.43783134e-02,  -7.09941391e-03,   7.77932310e+01]), array([  9.55239672e-01,   8.48133424e-01,   9.41803516e-01,
         6.00029472e-02,   1.16427455e-02,   3.91884410e-03,
         1.14186585e-02,   1.43783134e-02,   7.84959346e+01]), array([  9.52616068e-01,   8.51255512e-01,   9.45513746e-01,
         6.13091486e-02,   1.15153207e-02,  -2.74653979e-03,
         3.91884410e-03,   1.14186585e-02,   7.66670540e+01]), array([  9.67841234e-01,   8.54751516e-01,   9.53595272e-01,
         6.28853797e-02,   9.68865724e-03,   1.59824778e-02,
        -2.74653979e-03,   3.91884410e-03,   7.96194885e+01]), array([  9.73522265e-01,   8.58377874e-01,   9.60146018e-01,
         6.44142845e-02,   9.91815056...]
```

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? This doesn't seem to be the appropriate error.
Can you do ``X = np.array(x_learn)`` and give us ``X.shape`` and ``y_learn.shape``?

Comment: I am using version 0.16.1 of scikit-learn.
The output you asked for is:
`X.shape = (125, 9)`
`y_lean.shape = (125,)`

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have a problem with your shapes, try to do this before fitting your model:

```py
x_learn = x_learn.reshape(y_learn.shape)

# OR

y_learn = y_learn.reshape(x_learn.shape)
```

If it steel blosued than try to change it by `0` or upgrade your sklearn version because some version of sklearn have problem with `-1` as label

Comment: I have tried to replace the -1 to 0 - still got the error.
Also, I tried the reshape and it also didn't work.

Comment: yes.
To make things clearer. 
x_learn is a list of arrays
y_learn is an array

Comment: can you give me the output of `y_learn.shape` and `x_learn.shape`?

Comment: x_learn doesn't have a shape, as it is a list, but len(x_learn) returns 135 and y_learn.shape returns (135,)

Comment: ok, try this `X= numpy.array([x_learn])` and fit your model this way `clf.fit(X,y_learn)`

Comment: I tried and got this error:
Found array with dim 3. Expected <= 2

Comment: yes, it's because scikit-learn uses a 2-d convention (n_samples × n_features). Try this `X= numpy.array([x_learn]).reshape(len(y),3)`